# Show/hide an element with jQuery whilst changing the text of the toggle link

Tags: jquery, css

Have now spent about six hours trying to get this to work and have tried probably about 40 different variants to jQuery code with no luck so as you can imagine, starting to pull my hair out now over this...

Sample (condensed) HTML:-

```
<span class="price-info">
    <span class="price-including-tax">
        <span class="price">£100</span>
    </span>

    <span class="price-excluding-tax">
        <span class="price">£50</span>
    </span>
</span>

<span class="toggle">(Show ex VAT price)</span>
```

I just simply want to toggle the display of the ex VAT price when the link (.toggle) is clicked and change the text in the process.

I have tried jQuery .toggle, .addClass, .removeClass, .show, .hide - all sorts!

My current jQuery script looks like:-

```
          $j('.price-info .price-excluding-tax').hide();
            $j('.toggle').click(function() {
              var link = $j('.toggle');
                $j('.price-info .price-excluding-tax').toggle(function() {
                  if ($j('.toggle').is(":visible")) {
                    link.text('Show inc VAT price');
                  } else {
                    link.text('Show ex VAT price');
                  }
                });
            });
```

This is currently half-functioning as it will show the ex VAT price but immediately 'slide' back out of view. When I say slide, the above `.toggle` function is creating a transition in and out so that when the toggle is clicked, the .price-excluding-tax `<span>` is brought into / out of view with width, heigh and opacity transitions whereas I'm just after a simple `display: block` / `display:none;` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eDNH5/10/). It seems that once you append a function to `.toggle`, it functions differently.

I suspect that the ex VAT price might immediately slide back out of view because I am by default hiding it from view with `$j('.price-info .price-excluding-tax').hide();`, I don't know.

I don't really care whether I keep the above or not now, I just need something that works and that is to show the ex VAT price (whilst hiding the inc VAT price at the same time and also change the toggle text at the same time.

Before anyone asks for a jsFiddle, I've [created one](http://jsfiddle.net/2806y9r7/) already and the .toggle works fine and as I want - it just doesn't work on the site in question (so there could be some interference somewhere, no errors in console). The fiddle doesn't handle the text change though.

Comment: `if ($j('.toggle').is(":visible")) {`  Wait.. So if the text is visible, you change the text, and if it's invisible you chance it as well? That's different than in your fiddle?

Comment: @Jordumus Yeh that doesn't exist in the fiddle but basically, the text will be (Show ex VAT price) by default so when clicked, it needs to be changed to (Show inc VAT price). I don't doubt there is something wrong with my code above.

Comment: I've got this.  Is this what you wanted?  http://jsfiddle.net/jphtxdqk/2/

Comment: @ovaherenow just implemented this on the site and yes this has fixed the sliding in and out thing it was doing perfectly. It just isn't changing the text at the moment so still looking at it - thanks man.

Comment: Which text though?  Because in the jsfiddle code, it's changing the .toggle text.  Don't copy and paste my code because you require the "$j".

Comment: I've changed the `$` to `$j`. The `.toggle` span text doesn't change although it is being selected. Also the .toggle has broken now and the ex VAT price doesn't come in. Is it any use if you look at it [directly on the site](http://ps.clubnetdev.com/preparedness-survival/stoves-fuel-fire/avevay-stoves/anevay-traveller-stove-3-x-1000-s-flue-kit-with-spark-arrestor) in question (the prices at top of page)?

Comment: This seems like the job for a checkbox...

Comment: @jcuenod I don't follow I don't think but I don't want it to be a checkbox if that is what you meant. :)

Comment: @zigojacko what I mean is that this is something you toggle which is what a checkbox is for.

Comment: @zigojacko I put together an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions for your problem:

**Solution 1:**

use 2 divs for the text, and toggle those.. Like this:

```
<span class="toggleText">(Show ex VAT price)</span>
<span class="toggleText" style="display:none;">(Show inc VAT price)</span>
```

With jquery:

```
$j('.toggle').click(function() {
    $j('.price-info .price-excluding-tax').toggle();
    $j('.toggleText').toggle();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2806y9r7/1/)

**Solution 2:**

Improve your current code:

```
$j('.price-excluding-tax').toggle(function() {
    if ($j('.price-excluding-tax').is(":visible")) {
       $j(".toggle").text('Show inc VAT price');
    } else {
       $j(".toggle").text('Show ex VAT price');
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2806y9r7/4/)

Comment: I believe `$` needs changing to `$j` in second snippet and the second fiddle doesn't work for me. Still playing about with this, thanks.

Comment: Not working on [the website](http://ps.clubnetdev.com/preparedness-survival/stoves-fuel-fire/avevay-stoves/anevay-traveller-stove-3-x-1000-s-flue-kit-with-spark-arrestor) :( there is a second instance of `.price-excluding-tax` but I have made it more specific already by selecting `.price-info .price-excluding-tax`. No idea what's up with it.

Comment: Annoyingly, if I run the script in the console it does exactly what it is meant to...

Comment: where is the js located on your website? Can't find it immediately (might be because there are 200000 js files :p)

Comment: It's inline so saves you having to look through all the js files :) (constantly changing the js at the moment) - I think I've just figured out the issue though, the selectors need to be more specific due to multiple instances on the page when there is an upsell product, I'm getting somewhere I think, will confirm asap. Thanks.

Comment: Sorted ([better example](http://ps.clubnetdev.com/preparedness-survival/outdoor-camping/bcb-crusader)). The issue was because the selectors were matching multiple elements on the particular page I was testing on so all the attempts I had tried previously, probably were working fine, I was just clicking a different .toggle span to fire the jQuery. Doh. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for this. There is a **Pure CSS** solution to this problem.

I have connected two labels to a checkbox that functions as a toggle button. The one label makes the checkbox work like a toggle button, the other shows/hides the appropriate price.

Try out the snippet below.

```css
.price {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.price::before {
  content: "£";
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.price span {
  width: 60px;
  float: left;   
  margin-top: 5px; 
  text-align: right;
}

input#chkTax {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input#chkTax + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input#chkTax + label:before,
input#chkTax + label:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
input#chkTax + label:before {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  content: attr(data-off);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input#chkTax + label:after {
  background-color: #8ce196;
  border-color: #6cc176;
  content: attr(data-on);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
input#chkTax:checked + label:before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
input#chkTax:checked + label:after {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}

input#chkTax + label:hover:before {
    border-color: #bbb;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
input#chkTax + label:hover:after {
    border-color: #1ca136;
    background-color: #7cd186;
}


input#chkTax:checked + label + label .withtax,
.withouttax {
    display: block;
}
input#chkTax:checked + label + label .withouttax,
.withtax {
    display: none;
}

.price-info {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */     
}
```

```html
<div class="price-info">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkTax" />
    <label for="chkTax" class="cool-button" data-on="includes tax" data-off="excludes tax"></label>
    <label for="chkTax" class="price">
        <span class="withtax">
            1,000
        </span>
        <span class="withouttax">
            900
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Read More:**

A great article on what can be done can be found [here](http://callmenick.com/post/css-toggle-switch-examples)